# Regex issue retrieving hour

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/ZS8EWW/1) to check a paragraph and get some data from there.

```
([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2})[\s\D\s]+([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2}),(.+),(\s\w{1,2} de [\wç]+ de \d{4})?(\s\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4})?$
```

I need to get the hour, title and the date of this type of texts:

**EXAMPLE 1 :** This example the number 130 is causing the issue and I can't get the first hour

```
1:30pm to 4:30pm, Aniversário amigo matteo, Ana Montoya, Accepted, Location: Kids Buffet Infantil
Rua do Triunfo, 130, Brookling, Hello - SP, 04602-005, Brasil, November 23, 2022
```

**EXAMPLE 2 :** This is working correctly

```
8am to 9:30am, All Hearts meeting, Ana Montoya, Accepted, Location: https://us02web.zoom.us/j/1234?pwd=1234, November 21, 2022
```

Get the two hours, the text of the title and the final date

Comment: What is the issue here? I do see the 2 captured hours  https://regex101.com/r/60w1uB/1

Comment: FYI, `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?` to mean that the pattern is optional.

Comment: Will your string always be the same format and are you only looking for a regex answer? Also how do you determine *what* the title is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified regex with your sample input strings:

```js
[
  '1:30pm to 4:30pm, Aniversário amigo matteo, Ana Montoya, Accepted, Location: Kids Buffet Infantil Rua do Triunfo, 130, Brookling, Hello - SP, 04602-005, Brasil, November 23, 2022',
  '8am to 9:30am, All Hearts meeting, Ana Montoya, Accepted, Location: https://us02web.zoom.us/j/1234?pwd=1234, November 21, 2022'
].forEach(str => {
  let m = str.match(/^(\d\d?(?::\d\d)?[ap]m) to (\d\d?(?::\d\d)?[ap]m), *([^,]+).* ([a-z]+ \d+, \d{4})/i);
  console.log(m);
});
```

Output:

```
[
  "1:30pm to 4:30pm, Aniversário amigo matteo, Ana Montoya, Accepted, Location: Kids Buffet Infantil Rua do Triunfo, 130, Brookling, Hello - SP, 04602-005, Brasil, November 23, 2022",
  "1:30pm",
  "4:30pm",
  "Aniversário amigo matteo",
  "November 23, 2022"
]
[
  "8am to 9:30am, All Hearts meeting, Ana Montoya, Accepted, Location: https://us02web.zoom.us/j/1234?pwd=1234, November 21, 2022",
  "8am",
  "9:30am",
  "All Hearts meeting",
  "November 21, 2022"
]
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(` -- capture group 1 start
- `\d\d?` -- 1 or 2 digits
- `(?::\d\d)?` -- optional non-capture group for colon and 2 digits
- `[ap]m` -- literal `am` or `pm`
- `)` -- capture group 1 end
- `to` -- literal text
- `(\d\d?(?::\d\d)?[ap]m)` -- capture group 2, same as above
- `, *` -- comma and optional spaces
- `([^,]+)` -- title up to next comma
- `.*`  -- greedy scan to last space, followed by:
- `([a-z]+ \d+, \d{4})` -- date format `Mmmmm dd, yyyy`
- ignore case flag `i`

Answer (score -1):

You added the $ at the end, that means you force your expression to match the end of the string ( $ matches right after the last character in the string ).

1- The issue can be resolved quite simply by remove the $ at the end:

`([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2})[\s\D\s]+([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2}),(.+),(\s\w{1,2} de [\wç]+ de \d{4})?(\s\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4})?`

2- And better by adding ^ character in the left, to force the expression to match the begin  ( The character ^ matches the position before the first character in the string )

`^([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2})[\s\D\s]+([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2}),(.+),(\s\w{1,2} de [\wç]+ de \d{4})?(\s\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4})?`

3- Or by adding .* at the end of the regular expression ( before the $ ),

`([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2})[\s\D\s]+([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2}),(.+),(\s\w{1,2} de [\wç]+ de \d{4})?(\s\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4})?.*$`

In fact, A regular expression searsh to match a maximum. By adding .* at the end ( befor the $ character ), it will match a max from the right, so like as a left shift, the first occurence will be matched.

4- Or All those solutions :

`^([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2})[\s\D\s]+([0-9]{1,2}:{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[a-z]{0,2}),(.+),(\s\w{1,2} de [\wç]+ de \d{4})?(\s\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4})?.*$`

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: This desperately needs a supporting explanation.

Comment: Updated with explanation